Is there any way to securely pass a secret from a C program to a bash script?
Background: a web server communicates with a client, fetching a secret from them (for the sake of argument, a password which must be supplied to openssl). The server runs Apache, which runs a C (or whatever) program which collects the secret from the client.
The C program must now run openssl and supply it with the client secret. In practice, there are several commands, so it's easier to run a bash script, rather than running openssl directly. The C program is run by the Apache user, and the system sudoers file allows Apache to run a specific script as root without supplying a password.
The C program runs the script with either a system call, or popen/pclose, and must supply the secret to that script.
Question: is there any way to do this in which the password doesn't appear in the ps output, or in /proc/fd/cmdline, or similar?
The closest I've got so far is to get the script to run a second script, passing the password on stdin, which at least minimises the time during which the password is exposed, but this seems like a very poor solution.

Just passing it as an environment variable will prevent it from showing up in ps output or /proc/<pid>/cmdline, but it will be visible to any command run by the script (then again that is true of anything sent via stdin to the script as well)

But environment variables show up in /proc/<pid>/environ (on Linux). The permissions on environ are stricter than cmdline, that might be enough depending on the specific scenario.

@StephenKitt IIRC you need to be root to access that? Or are the permissions looser than that?

@muru readable only by the process owner, so root and the process owner. Mounting /proc with hidepid=1 does the same with cmdline.

if /proc/<pid>/environ is too open, create another pipe, write the secret there and have the child process read from it (passing the fd number as a command line arg or such; IIRC openssl supports that directly). Or you could create a temp file, but of course that could be read also by other processes with appropriate permissions.

@muru - but I'd have to execute two system calls - the first to set/export the var. When system returns the new environment has surely gone?

@ilkkachu: if I write a temp file, surely the command to create it with the secret will be visible in ps? Similarly, using file descriptors - how can I actually create the pipe without explicitly using a visible secret?

Actually, I wonder if the way to do this is to use popen and use the pipe to write the secret to the script...

@QF0 If you're set on using system(), then  use setenv() to modify your environment, which will then be inherited by the commands executed using system(). Otherwise use execve() or the like where you can set a custom environment directly.

Why would the command be visible if you do something like (pseudocode, and I don't remember enough C to make it C-like, sorry) f=file_handle; printf '%s\n' password > f and then run something like system("your_command < $(cat the_file)") pass the file you created to the process? The variable password will only be seen in the C program, right? (note that I know very little about this so I may very well be wrong here).

@QF0, exactly what terdon and muru said. Even if you do use system() to run the child program (and TBH it does make it much easier than doing the fork+exec dance manually), there's no reason not to do simple things like setting envvars or writing to files from the C program. Just generate a unique name for the temp file and make sure to create it with permissions that only allow the same user to read it. (Call umask(0077) first.)

First, @muru: thanks, I hadn't thought of setenv, and that does seem a simple solution. I can't immediately see how to do a file-based solution without exposing the secret somewhere. But... I think there is a better answer. I've just done a test program that creates two pipes, and forks a child which runs the script with execl, while the parent C code writes to the child stdin on one pipe, and reads stdout on the other. This works great, so the script  now reads the password on stdin (and returns keys on stdout). Seems good so far, and I don't think there's any 'leakage'.

Since you're in C land, rather than invoking the openssl binary, have you considered using the openssl C library to do the equivalent things?  Then you wouldn't need to invoke a shell script and communicate a secret across application boundaries.

@QF0 nice, but none of that is any safer from root than environment variables

If root is untrustworthy, then the whole system is, and the safest thing is not to use it for sensitive data.
